# Remove Code White-space (WordPress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Basically I have a WordPress loop and I need all the code to be compressed and all unnecessary white-space to be stripped like so:

```
<article><p>Content</p></article><article><p>Content</p></article><article><p>Content</p></article>
```

I am including the loop file using:

```
<?php get_template_part('library/inc/loop'); ?>
```

Just wondering if there is a simple way like:

```
<?php trim( get_template_part('library/inc/loop') ); ?>
```

If this is possible all my problems would be solved, any help is much appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: I think this would be much more work than it's worth, the problem is distinguishing which white-space is actually considered content (Text elements, attributes, etc.), and which is just white-space between tags.  Is there a reason you want to do this, or are you just looking to save $0.02 a month on bandwidth?

Comment: Ah, well the reason is because I'm using a grid layout which depends on "display:inline-block" which fails if there is white-space between the grid items.

Comment: You would probably be better off modifying the template itself to remove white-space between columns, otherwise, you will have to write complex code to determine what is white-space you should and should not remove.  This logic will be much more difficult than a simple find/replace.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all leading and trailing whitespaces within HTML elements, you might use

```
// Remove whitespace before '<'
$html = preg_replace('~\s+<~', '<', $html);
// Remove whitespace after '>'
$html = preg_replace('~>\s+~', '>', $html);
```

This will leave any whitespace within text intact.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the "back end" of WordPress, however you could try

`str_replace(" ","",$data);//Find whitespace " " and replace with ""`

To clarify: whitespace when outputting, or whitespace in the source code?

Or as you put try using trim(). I hope this helps you.